# Why my backbone.js collection reset is only adding 1 model

Tags: javascript, collections, backbone.js

The collection in question grabs a bunch of Friends, and then it uses `reset` to save all the new Friends. The problem I am having, is that it only adds 1 friend to the collection.

I did a `console.log` on `cModels` and it was showing over 300 objects in the Array, so I know there isn't only 1. Any reason why the reset would only be adding 1?

Here is my collection:

```
FriendsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: UserModel,

    getFriends: function () {
        $.post(baseUrl + dataFriendsUrl, $.proxy(function(data) {
            var friends = $.parseJSON(data);
            var cModels = [];

            for(var key in friends.data) {                
                var user = new UserModel();
                user.set({
                    fbid: friends.data[key].id,
                    username: friends.data[key].name
                });

                cModels.push(user);
            }

            this.reset(cModels);

            console.log(this);

        }, this));
    }
});
```

And the models look fine, after inspecting them with the developer tools.

Comment: Backbone's collection.reset just resets the collection and then calls collection.add on whatever was passed to it.  Add is pretty good about throwing errors when you have a problem, so I'm surprised you're not seeing any.  The actual line which does the adding is `splice.apply(this.models, [index, 0].concat(models));`.  You might want to try adding a `debugger` or `console.log(this.models, models, index)` line right before it to see if your full set of models are making it to that point.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's probably because the models have the same id.

A Backbone collection does not allow models with duplicate id values. (see this [commit](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/commit/18fba5772430f667c0d3cfb88d880039381c25fa))

Comment: If that were the case though OP should be getting an error "Can't add the same model to a collection twice"

Comment: He was right - I added `id: key` within the `set`, and it fixed it.

Comment: @machineghost the commit I referenced removed raising that error

Comment: Thanks.  I was getting ready to start tossing computer equipment across the room.  I had a collection of models that were read-only (basically stats collected about other data in the DB, rather than anything a user could persist), so I thought id didn't matter in such a case.  But it does...